# SqlAlchemy: Cancel event handler action

Tags: events, sqlalchemy

Is it possible when I'm attached to an attribute event ("append") in the handler to cancel the append action?

Lets say I have some validation in the handler for every appended record and if the record does not pass the validation I want to be skiped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [sqlalchemy.orm.validates](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates) for another way of performing the validation, which results in somewhat cleaner code. According to the documentation:

> The function can then raise validation exceptions to halt the process
>   from continuing (where Python’s built-in ValueError and AssertionError
>   exceptions are reasonable choices), or can modify or replace the value
>   before proceeding. The function should otherwise return the given
>   value.

```
class User(...):
    # ...
    addresses = relationship("Address")

    @validates('addresses')
    def _modify_addresses(self, key, target):
        if target.phone is None
            raise ValueError("User addresses must have a phone number!")
        return target
```

According to the documentation, you can modify the value added to the collection. But to completely avoid adding it, you need to raise an Exception. Obviously, you need to handle this exception in the outer code:

```
def _add_addresses(user, address_list):
    for address in address_list:
        try:
            user.addresses.append(address)
        catch ValueError as _exc:
            logging.warn("Could not add Address [%s] to the User [%s]", address, user.name)
```